# facebook app doesn't work on genymotion emulator 2.0.1 even if google play is installed

Tags: android, facebook, android-emulator, genymotion

I have installed facebook app on genymotion emulator `nexus` `4.1.1`
version `2.0.1` of `Genymotion`.

But it doesn't work...

After success of installation , I have seen a shortcut of the Facebook app on home 
but when I press one black screen appear for about three seconds and close

Do you any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: if you want to install facebook app in ur emulator try this emulator i havent test if for facebook but this is a good one http://www.bluestacks.com/

Comment: It works well, You need to uninstall and install a fresh copy from google play store

Comment: facebook doesn't try-catch anything, so if your device doesn't have libraries like: Google Play Services (!= market) it will make your app crash. As sad as you can read it.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the logcat for your emulator? It probably has some trace of the crash and that will lead you to the solution, probably a missing dependency,as mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

Genymotion emulator does have few issues.
so if possible that try to check facebook in browser.